# What does the following c code do?

Tags: c

```
#define SRC_ASCLIN_ASCLIN0_RX (*(volatile Ifx_SRC_SRCR*)0xF0038084u)
```

Here `SRC_ASCLIN_ASCLIN0_RX`  means ASCLIN(Async/Sync serial LIN Comm) Receive Service Request.

I know that the macro is used to point at the address `0xF0038084u`. But I want real time examples.

Am working on UART development on Infineon microcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

The macro, when expanded by the preprocessor, cast the integer literal as an address, a pointer to `Ifx_SRC_SRCR`, then dereferences the pointer so you can get or set the value of the memory stored at that specific address.

So you could write e.g.

```
Ifx_SRC_SRCR value = SRC_ASCLIN_ASCLIN0_RX;
```

or

```
SRC_ASCLIN_ASCLIN0_RX = some_other_value;
```

It basically equivalent to doing e.g.

```
int an_integer = 6;
int *pointer_to_an_integer = &an_integer;

*pointer_to_an_integer = 10;  // Equivalent to SRC_ASCLIN_ASCLIN0_RX = some_other_value above
```